# How to do insertion sort in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: insertion-sort, microprocessors, 8085

```
LXI D 8021
MVI B 01
MOV C B------------L3
MOV L E
MOV H D
DCX H
LDAX D
CMP M--------------L2
JNC L1
STA 8030
MOV A M
STAX D
LDA 8030
DCX H
DCR C
JNZ L2
INX H---------------L1
MOV M A
INX D
INR B
MOV A B
CPI 05
JNZ L3
HLT
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The above-mentioned code can be used to implement insertion sort on the 8085 Microprocessor Architecture Trainer Kit.

Comment: So this isn't really a question, but rather an answer? Please take some time to go over my first comment again, and read the links to understand why your "question" isn't a good one (and really not a question or a problem at all).